# JDBCドライバでDBサーバ接続時にネットワーク情報の取得エラーが発生する

Tags: java, network

現在、JavaでSQL ServerにJDBCドライバ経由でアクセスし情報を取得するプログラムを作成しており、初回のDB接続時にエラーが発生し、接続に失敗する現象が発生しています。(発生頻度は毎回ではなく、2週間に1回程度です(回数にして500回に1回程度))

どの点に着目すれば良いか、ご教授いただけないでしょうか。
(仮想環境のネットワークカードのバグなどあるのでしょうか。。。)

環境は以下になります。
OS：Windows Server 2016
DB：SQL Server 2016
JDBCドライバ：sqljdbc41.jar
Java：1.7.0_67
VMWareの仮想環境上で動作させています。

以下にエラー内容を抜粋します。

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.Error: IP Helper Library GetAdaptersAddresses function failed

Caused by: java.lang.Error: IP Helper Library GetAdaptersAddresses function failed
    at java.net.NetworkInterface.getAll(Native Method)
    at java.net.NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator.addNetworkAdapterInfo(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator.getSystemEntropy(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom$SeederHolder.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom.engineNextBytes(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.UUID.randomUUID(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1317)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:993)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:829)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: JDKのバグの可能性がありそうですね。Javaをアップグレードしてみたらどうなりますか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。現状、「1.7.0_67」でしか動作保障をしないという制約があり、アップグレードができない状況です。本来、アップグレードして調査すべきかとは思いますが。。

Comment: Windows版Java runtimeのはるか奥深くで呼ばれている`GetAdaptersAddresses`がエラー終了しているようですね。[ドキュメント](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersaddresses)を読むと、ネットワークの状態によってはエラー終了することがあるようです。「初回のDB接続時」と言うことですが、どう言う意味で初回ですか?「毎日」「あるアプリを起動してから」「VMWareの仮想環境の再起動直後」…?

Comment: 「初回」とはJavaのプログラムの処理の最初と言う意味です(DB接続して、DBから値を取得して、処理を行う流れです。初回とは意味合いが違ってますね。。)。Javaのプログラムはタスクスケジューラで定期的に実行するようになっていて、月～金で1日あたり50回程度実行されています。